# Programa básico de login no funciona

Tags: javascript, login

Escribí este programa básico pero por alguna razón no aparece ninguna "alert" cuando hago click en el botón.

```
<script>
function logg(){
   var usuario = document.getElementById(usuario).value;
   var clave = document.getElementById(clave).value;
   if(usuario=="test" && clave=="ing"){
      alert("Well done");
   }
   else{
      alert("Not well done");
   }
}
</script>

User: <input type="text" id="usuario" value="" /><br />
Pass: <input type="password" id="clave" value="" /><br />
<input onClick="logg();" type="button" id="enviar" value="Enviar" />
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow en español. Por favor, edita la pregunta usando el castellano para que todos los que usamos esta página podamos entenderte.

Comment: Perdón, pensé que estaba en Stackoverflow en inglés. Ya lo he editado.

Comment: Para ver esta clase de inconvenientes sirve mucho ver la consola javacript del navegador que estás usando (suele estar dentro de u.na opción/menu de los navegadores para desarroladores).

Comment: Lo tendré en cuenta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas llamando mal el id del elemento, debería ir entre comillas, actualmente está así:

```
var usuario = document.getElementById(usuario).value;
var clave = document.getElementById(clave).value;
```

Debería ir así:

```
var usuario = document.getElementById('usuario').value;
var clave = document.getElementById('clave').value;
```

```js
function logg(){
   var usuario = document.getElementById('usuario').value;
   var clave = document.getElementById('clave').value;
   if(usuario=="test" && clave=="ing"){
      alert("Well done");
   }
   else{
      alert("Not well done");
   }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Login Basico</title>
</head>
<body>
User: <input type="text" id="usuario" value="" /><br />
Pass: <input type="password" id="clave" value="" /><br />
<input onClick="logg();" type="button" id="enviar" value="Enviar" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ahora funciona correctamente.

Comment: @LuchoPelado Dado que la respuesta soluciona la pregunta y te ha ayudado, te sugiero que la marques como [aceptada](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Listo, soy nuevo aquí ;D

Comment: Por cierto, hay alguna manera de poder "bypassear" este login? Y cómo lo podría evitar? Es decir, cualquiera podría ver el código fuente y ver qué condiciones son necesarias para "loguearse".

Comment: Si lo dejas tal como está sí, cualquiera puede ver el codigo del lado del cliente, si quisieras dar mayor seguridad deberías hacer el login del lado del servidor, o podrías usar alguna librería en javascript para encriptar el el password, pero en todo caso del lado del cliente seguiría siendo visible el password, lo mas seguro es hacerlo del lado del servidor.